# Precise meaning of "family of hypersurfaces"

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition

I am a little confused by the term *family of hypersurfaces*. For simplicity, let $Y$ be a projective curve (and also given the embedding, so we can talk about the line bundle $\mathcal O_Y(1)$). When I say $X \to Y$ is a *(flat) family of hypersurfaces in $\mathbb P^n$ of degree $d$*, I may mean the following:

(i) $\pi\colon X \to Y$ is a (flat) morphism with every fiber isomorphic to some hypersurface in $\mathbb P^n$ of degree $d$. (I believe the flatness is followed from the fact that each fibre is isomorphic to some hypersurface in $\mathbb P^n$ of degree $d$, at least under some very weak assumption)

(ii) The conditions in (i), moreover we assume $X\subset  Y\times \mathbb P^n$ and $\pi$ is the restriction of the first projection.

(iii) The conditions in (ii), moreover we assume $X\subset  Y\times \mathbb P^n$ and $\pi$ is given by zero locus of some secion in $\mathcal O_Y(1)\boxtimes\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}(d)$.

(iv) The conditions in (iii), moreover we assume the embedding of $Y$ is $Y\subset \mathbb |\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}(d)|$.

I want to know that, are those contions all equivalent?

Comment: I'm not following the claim that the fibres are isomorphic. Hypersurfaces aren't all isomorphic? Maybe I'm misunderstanding something here.

Comment: @jgon Yes you are right. I want to mean that they are all isomorphic to degree $d$ hypersurfaces in $\mathbb P^n$, hence they have the same Hilbert polynomials, and hence flat. I edited it.

Comment: Flatness certainly does not follow from your assumption - the criterion with Hilbert polynomials requires your morphism to be projective. After all - there are many choices of isomorphism and the Hilbert polynomial is data dependent on your embedding!

I think here's an example - consider $X = \mathbb{A}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1 $ and $Y = \{\infty\} \times \mathbb{P}^1$, and consider the map $X\sqcup Y \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ given by projection to the first coordinate. Then this is not flat, but each fiber is a $\mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: (ii) $\implies$ (iii) should just be a a consequence of Exercise 28.3.C in Vakil

Comment: @loch Yes, I think we also need $\pi$ is proper in (i).

Comment: @loch I didn't see how Ex. 28.3.C implies $\mathcal I_X$ is of the form $\mathcal O_Y(-1) \boxtimes \mathcal O(-d)$. Could you explain a little bit?